# NSWindow Modal Problems

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, modal-dialog, delay, nswindow

I'm running a modal window in my application, which works fine. The problem however seems to be dismissing the window.

While the window closes, it takes at least 20 seconds for the application to continue (I show the modal window at startup), but it will continue instantly if I click on its dock icon.

Here's how I close the modal window:

```
[NSApp stopModal];
[updaterWindow orderOut:self];
[updaterWindow close];
```

I've tried various things to get the Application to continue faster, such as manually switching to the main run loop and speaking to the main window directly (asking it to become the key window), which all did not work. Same as before, 20 seconds wait or instant load when clicking on the dock icon.

What can cause something like this? I'm really baffled.

**Edit:**

My modal window is actually created in a really simple way. I run my window as modal:

```
[NSApp runModalForWindow:updaterWindow];
```

When I am done with things, I close it:

```
[NSApp stopModal];
[updaterWindow orderOut:self];
[updaterWindow close];
```

The window goes away, but it needs a click to the dock icon or anywhere on the screen for the app to continue.

Comment: What does the time profiler from Instruments tell you about what it is doing during those 20 seconds?

Comment: Also, how are you starting the modal loop for the window?

Comment: I am starting it with `NSApp`'s `runModalForWindow:`. Will check Instruments in a minute.

Comment: Instruments crashes: `Application Specific Information:
abort() called
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Couldn't load plug-in 'com.apple.OpenGLESAnalyzerInstrument''` Just great..

Comment: Please post the code (including surrounding context) in which you begin the modal dialog, including, if applicable, any non-default code in `main.m`. For example, are you invoking it before you make the primary call to `NSApplicationMain()`, or if you are starting it within your controller class?

Comment: main.m is unchanged. Will edit my post to show the code.

Comment: Are you working with Leopard? Snow Leopard? Lion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing something similar in my app at the moment: I have an IBAction method that calls the modal window:

```
-(IBAction)showMyModalWindow:(id)sender {
    [theModalWindow makeKeyWindow];
    NSInteger retVal = [NSApp runModalForWindow:theModalWindow];
    [theModalWindow close];
    //continue and do somethin according the value in retVal
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
}
```

In this case `theModalWindow` is in it's own nib file has an NSObject in it that deals with the ok and cancel button to dismiss `theWindow`, by way of example here's the cancel button callback:

```
-(IBAction)cancelButton:(id)sender
{
    [NSApp stopModalWithCode:errAuthorizationCanceled];
}
```

The last line in `showMyModalWindow:` method seems to be what's needed in my case by sending the app forward... Hope that's of some use!

Todd.